# jQuery Chained: How to unchain chained dropdown?

Tags: jquery, chained

I used this plugin: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained

I've chained dropdown, and in some event, I want to unchain and rebind chain based on the event.

Here some example:

```
<select id="first">
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
<option value="c" class="a">C</option>
<option value="d" class="a">D</option>
<option value="e" class="b">E</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="unchain" />
```

The Javascript will be:

```
$('#second').chained('#first');
$('#unchain').change(function(){
  if ($(this).prop('checked'))
  {
    // how to unchain the chained dropdown?
  }
});
```

Have tried `$('#second').unbind('chained');` but didn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try calling `$('#first').unbind('change');`. Although this would unbind all change events from that dropdown.

Comment: ah, yes. it tried with `$('#second').unbind('change');` and if want to chained back, just `$('#second').bind('change');`

Comment: First of all, you should `unbind` change event from `#first` select, not `#second`. But this is still won't work, because `chained` plugin filters all non-matching options from `#second` select, so when you "unchain" (`unbind` from change event), the `#second` select will have some options cut off (i.e. lost forever). It can only work if after unchaining you would reinitialize `#second` select with full set of options.

Comment: I've created simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/e6kyy9gr/) with possible solution. Would it work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chained plugin filters all non-matching options from `#second` select, so when you "unchain" (unbind from change event), the `#second` select will have some options cut off (i.e. lost forever).

It can only work if after unchaining you would reinitialize `#second` select with full set of options. So something like this should be done:

```
$(function () {
    // remember #second select
    var secondCopy = $('#second').clone();
    $('#second').chained('#first');
    $('#unchain').change(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
            $('#second').chained('#first');
        }
        else{
            $('#first').unbind('change');
            // remember selected value:
            var value = $('#second').val();
            // populate #second select with remembered options
            $('#second').html(secondCopy.html());
            // set saved value
            $('#second').val(value);
        }
    });
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/e6kyy9gr/)

Comment: ah, you were right. unbind `#second` will remove the options in `#second`. your solution worked for me. thanks!