# how to remove or destroy chained from select once it is initialized? (jquery.chained.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chained-select

I have two dropdown `#a` and `#b`. After chaining `#b` to `#a`

```
 $("#b").chained("#a");
```

How do I unchain `#b` from `#a`?

Comment: `chained()` is not a standard method, so I guess you're using a library? If so, you should check their documentation

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908781/jquery-chained-how-to-unchain-chained-dropdown

Comment: I am using 'jquery.chained.js' plugin. Thanks @RoryMcCrossan